# Android equivalent of Nibs?

Tags: android, user-interface, graphical-layout-editor, android-layout-editor

I am an iOS developer who is new to Android dev.
I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to nibs in Android dev.

For example:

- I subclass Button to programmatically define behaviors like having the button spin on touchdown (similar to creating a .swift file and subclassing UIButton)
- I can design the look of the button in XML once (similar to editing the xib file)
- I can drag my new custom button from Android Studio's Layout Editor onto other views

[image: what I have so far]

I already know that subclassing views will make them appear in the palette, I just don't know how to design the look of a subclassed view using XML.

When I try to drag additional things into my button, it doesn't work (probably because I'm subclassing Button and not ViewGroup).

Answer (score 0):

In android studio You can create some reusable.xml file in resource's layout directory, then create a new reusable.java java class and in constructor of this class use layout inflater of android studio to inflate reusable.xml view. Then you can do with inflated view what you want.